# Require with parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to seperate my routes from the app.js file.

The login route need a firebase instance.

**routes/auth.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(firebase) {
    ...
}

module.exports = router;
```

**app.js**

```
var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
    ...
}

firebase.initializeApp(config);

var auth = require('./routes/auth')(firebase)

app.use('/admin', auth)
```

When i start the server, it gives me a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined` error...

It points to the require statement in app.js:

`var auth = require('./routes/auth')(firebase)`

---

Edit:

When i try to access `/auth` it given me a **Cannot GET /auth** error..

**app.js**

```
const PORT = 8081

...

var auth = require('./routes/auth')(firebase)

app.use('/auth', auth)

app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.log(util.format('Example app listening on port %d!', PORT))
})
```

**routes/auth.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

module.exports = function(firebase) {
  router.get('/auth', function(req, res) {
    res.send('hi')
  })

  return router
}
```

The url im trying to access is http://localhost:8081/auth

Comment: Yes, the error points to the require statement

Comment: Sorry, i updated the question!

Comment: Your auth.js, has 2 exports..  So your last export will win.  I think what your after is more like -> `module.exports = function(firebase) { return router; }`

Comment: @Keith thanks it wont give an error anymore, i updates the post again. Im trying to get a page but it gives me the Cannot GET ... error

Comment: What url are you trying, and do you have any routes on the router?..

Comment: Oh, just noticed your showing your route now.  Well with that route, you url would need to be  `/auth/auth`,  I'm assuming you want  /auth to go here, so your router.get wants to be  router.get('/') as you have a router inside a router.  Or alternatively do  `app.use('/', auth);`

Comment: Because the route is in an sub-directory it will add the name of the directory to the url?

Comment: Well app.use, is giving you your root url, and then inside you auth.js your then saying router.get('/auth')..  so if you add your root url to your get url, you get  /auth/auth

Comment: Make sense, thanks. Please post the answer, so i can accept/upvote yours :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first problem..

Your auth.js, has 2 exports.. So your last export will win. I think what your after is more like -> module.exports = function(firebase) { return router; }

The second problem was that your using app.use(url, obj)..  The url you provide will become the root node of your middleware..  So when you did router.get(url, callback), what's then happening is the the url will become  `/aut/auth`

2 options here,

1. Don't supply a root,  eg.  `app.use(auth)`
2. Remove the url from your get, as it's already been set from `app.use`,  so `router.get('/', callback)`